# Use Android library module as dependency to pure Java module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, module, android-library

I have an android library module in Android Studio, named `:androidtestlib`, and a "pure" Java module, named `:javatest`. I want to share code between them.

I can set `:javatest` as a dependancy to `:androidtestlib`.

However, since I have already written many classes in `:androidtestlib`, I want to set this one as a dependency to `:javatest`. When using `implementation project(':androidtestlib')`, build fails with:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':androidtestlib:MyClass.main()'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':androidtestlib:runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :javatest.
     Required by:
         project :androidtestlib
> The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 7, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :javatest:
          - debugAndroidTestCompile
          - debugAndroidTestRuntime
...
```

If I use the deprecated `compile project(path: ':androidtestlib', configuration: 'default')`, Gradle syncs successfully and even code completion works. Building however fails since it can't find the package from the android library module:

```
error: package com.test.some_package does not exist
import com.test.some_pacakge.MyClass;
                             ^
```

Is there a way to make this work and use the Android Library module as a dependency to the pure Java module?

Comment: As i understood you trying to set set `:javatest` as a dependancy to `:androidtestlib` and vice-versa?

Comment: I can set `:javatest` as a dependancy to `:androidtestlib`. I can't do the opposite. In general, I want to set an Android Library module as a dependency to a Java module.